# How do I pass certain route parameters from a screen function to a navigation header button in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and am basically wondering how to pass information from one screen to another if the button that triggers the shift from one screen to another is in the navigation class.

For example, If I have a screen:

```
export default function Screen() {
    const data = ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

and another screen with a SectionList section that requires that information:

```
 const data = [
    {
      title: "",
      data: {route.params?.data},
    },
```

and finally within the navigation tab a custom navbar header:

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="Screen"
        component={ChatScreen}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          headerRight: () => (
            <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Screen", {data: *get data from 
             Screen here*)}>
              <Ionicons
                name="ellipsis-horizontal"
                size={25}
                color="#5C6AEF"
                style={{ marginBottom: 2 }}
              />
            </Pressable>
          ),
        })}
      />
```

basically, how do I call the information from Screen in the Navigation tab to pass to the SectionList screen?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you getting the "route" parameter in SectionList? Are you using the useRoute hook from @react-navigation/native?

Comment: Yes correct! that's the way I learned how to do it, except I imported it from @react-navigation/core. I don't know if that makes a difference though.

Comment: The useRoute should be imported from @react-navigation/native according to the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route

Try changing your import to that and see if it fixes the problem. I can't see anything wrong with the example you provided otherwise.